# How do I join lines using space and comma

Tags: bash, shell, awk, cut, tr

I have the file that contains content like:

```
IP
111
22
25
```

I want to print the output in the format `IP 111,22,25`.

I have tried `tr ' ' ,` but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following awk script will do the requested:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","} FNR==1{first=$0;next} {val=val?val OFS $0:$0} END{print first FS val}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now.

```
awk '                      ##Starting awk program here.
BEGIN{                     ##Starting BEGIN section here of awk program.
  OFS=","                  ##Setting OFS as comma, output field separator.
}                          ##Closing BEGIN section of awk here.
FNR==1{                    ##Checking if line is first line then do following.
  first=$0                 ##Creating variable first whose value is current first line.
  next                     ##next keyword is awk out of the box keyword which skips all further statements from here.
}                          ##Closing FNR==1 BLOCK here.
{                          ##This BLOCK will be executed for all lines apart from 1st line.
  val=val?val OFS $0:$0    ##Creating variable val whose values will be keep concatenating its own value.
}
END{                       ##Mentioning awk END block here.
  print first FS val       ##Printing variable first FS(field separator) and variable val value here.
}' Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name here which is getting processed by awk.
```

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to `paste`

```
$ paste -sd " ," file
IP 111,22,25
```

Normally what `paste` does is it writes to standard output lines consisting of sequentially corresponding lines of each given file, separated by a <tab>-character. The option `-s` does it differently. It states to paste each line of the files sequentially with a <tab>-character as a delimiter. When using the  `-d` flag, you can give a list of delimiters to be used instead of the <tab>-character. Here I gave as a list `" ,"` indicating, use space and then only commas.

Answer (score 2):

In pure Bash:

```
# Read file into array
mapfile -t lines < infile

# Print to string, comma-separated from second element on
printf -v str '%s %s' "${lines[0]}" "$(IFS=,; echo "${lines[*]:1}")"

# Print
echo "$str"
```

Output:

```
IP 111,22,25
```

Comment: Or, for a funny one: `IFS=, eval 'str="${lines[0]} ${lines[*]:1}"'; echo "$str"`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with:

```
{ read a; read b; read c; read d; } < file
echo "$a $b,$c,$d"
```

---

This will also work:

```
xargs printf "%s %s,%s,%s" < file
```

Comment: This requires you to know exactly how many lines there are.

Answer (score 1):

Try `cat file.txt | tr '\n' ',' | sed "s/IP,/IP /g"`

`tr` deletes new lines, `sed` changes `IP,111,22,25` into `IP 111,22,25`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about the sed :(. 1- Also what if we have random IP's in place of IP? How do we sperate IP from the PORTS?  2- it is printing comma even after the last 25`,`

Comment: `sed` is a find and replace so you can do whatever you want with it. It works with regex.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
$ cat captain.txt
IP
111
22
25

$ perl -0777 -ne ' @k=split(/\s+/); print $k[0]," ",join(",",@k[1..$#k]) ' captain.txt
IP 111,22,25
$
```